# Register post type getting error 404

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I've an issue with custom post type, I've created a custom post type called `treatments` and the rewritten URL for `http://example.com/treatments` (template taxonomy-treatments.php) not works, and the single page (template `single-treatments.php`) for `http://example.com/treatments/example`.

It shows 404 error (I have updated the permanent links), the only thing that works so far is to call the loop from the front page.

What do you suggest me? The code that I've used to add the custom post type is:

```
function post_types() {
    register_post_type( 'treatments', array(
        'labels'             => array(
            'name'               => 'treatments',
            'singular_name'      => 'treatment',
            'all_items'          => 'add treatments',
            'add_new_item'       => 'Add Item to treatments',
            'edit_item'          => 'Edit treatment',
            'search_items'       => 'Seach treatment',
            'not_found'          => 'No items found in Treatments.',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No treatment items found in the trash',
            'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'treatments', 'with_front' => true ),
        ),
        'public'             => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-slides',
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes', 'common' ),
    ) );
    flush_rewrite_rules( false );
}

add_action( 'init', 'post_types' );


// register taxonomy
function create_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'category',
        array(
            'treatments'
        ),
        array(
            'labels'        => array(
                'name' => 'Categorias'
            ),
            'show_ui'       => true,
            'show_tagcloud' => false,
            'rewrite'       => array(
                'slug' => 'treatments'
            )
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_taxonomies' );
```

Comment: Get rid of `flush_rewrite_rules( false );`, shouldn't flush rewrite rules on every page load, which is what this will do.

Comment: I deleted it but it does not work

Comment: Your taxonomy has the same slug as your post type, this will make one or the other 404 depending on which you register first. You're also registering a taxonomy named `category`, which is already a built-in taxonomy.